# WildFly 23.0.2 BASIC authentication not working

Tags: java, rest, wildfly, basic-authentication

I can't understand why the BASIC authentication method isn't working.
I tried to secure a resource on the url api/hello-world (it's the first time) with the HTTP BASIC auth method (code below).
But, it's completely not working, the resource is not protected when accessed, and browser shows no login form.

jboss-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_10_0.xsd"
       version="10.0">
   <security-domain>ApplicationDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0"

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Hello World</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/api/hello-world</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>user</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
        <realm-name>ApplicationRealm</realm-name>
    </login-config>
</web-app>
```

Testing with Insomnia, the resource results not protected, responding always with 200.

Comment: What URL are you going to?  If you pass anything else then your path isn't matched.  Do you want `/api/hello-world/*`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but my resource is on the path `/api/hello-world`. Indeed, i can access the resource from browser on this URL; the problem is that isn't showing the BASIC login form.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Wildfly 26.0.1. In older Versions it worked with this configiration in the `standalone.xml` (Example from 18.0.1):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:10.0" default-security-domain="other">
```

where `other` is the default value in the `xsd`. `other` is defined as default security domain in the `domain::ejb3` section only, not in undertow. This might be wrong, but it worked. In Wildfly 26.0.1 it no longer worked with a similar configuration.

However I got it running by changing the `default-security-domain` in the undertow section from `other` to `ApplicationDomain`.

```
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:12.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="ApplicationDomain" statistics-enabled="${wildfly.undertow.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}">
```

Don't know if this helps in your case, as well.